# Why do I have recursive calls of computed function in vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have the following code in my Vuejs app:
I bring some initial data in my app:

```
const app = new Vue({
    router,
    store,
    mounted: function() {
        var that = this;
        $.get("/initial_data/", {}, function(data) {
            that.$store.dispatch('set_initial_data', data);
        });
    }
}).$mount('#app');
```

And then I have this component:

```
var myComponent = Vue.component('root', {
    ...
    data() {
        return {
            counters: []
        }
    },
    computed: {
        ride() {
            if (this.$store.getters.data["rides"]) {
                const that = this;

                var limit = this.$store.getters.data["rides"][0]["Movements"].split(" : ");
                that.counters.push(0);
                console.log(that.counters);
                var counter1 = setInterval(function () {
                    that.counters.splice(0, 1, that.counters[0] + 1);
                }, 10000);
                return this.$store.getters.data["rides"][0];
            }
            else {
                return "";
            }
        },
        ...
    }
});
```

The problem is that when I don't have counter1 I get into ride function only once.

And when I add counter1, I have recursive calls to my ride function, and I get this in my console:

```
[0, __ob__: Observer]
all.js:196 [1, 0, __ob__: Observer]
all.js:196 [2, 0, 0, __ob__: Observer]
all.js:196 [3, 0, 0, 0, __ob__: Observer]
all.js:196 [4, 0, 0, 0, 0, __ob__: Observer]
all.js:196 [5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, __ob__: Observer]
all.js:196 [6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, __ob__: Observer]
all.js:196 [7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, __ob__: Observer]
```

Can someone explain why this is happening?

I would expect still to access the ride function only once.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you have `setInterval` assigned on variable `counter1` and as suposed It would be invoked each 10k ms.

Into the setInterval you are changing the `counter` and when that change happened computed property `ride` would re-evaluate.

Hope It's clearer now.